# When to use the abverbial form of maximal: maximally?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives, adverbs

Could the following sentence considered to be a correct use case of the adverbial form of the word *maximal* in English?

> Use underflow to set the maximally possible value of used datatype.

When should one use *maximal*, and when should one use *maximally*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you have given, *maximum* would be the right word:

> Use underflow to set the maximum possible value of the data type used.

*Maximally* is usually found as an adverb that modifies an adjective, such as *maximally efficient*.

Comment: *Maximal* makes a fine enough adjective (as these things go), but for a noun only *maximum* will do.  However, you also regularly see *the maximum possible value*, and no one would bat an eyelash at that one.

Comment: Lest it were unclear, I’m agreeing with you. [See here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maximum+possible%2Cmaximal+possible%2Cmaximally+possible&year_start=1908&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaximum%20possible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaximal%20possible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaximally%20possible%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Thank you bye and @tchrist for the quick help and revising my question.

Comment: I agree, @tchrist, but there is a fine distinction in this case. *Maximal* would not work, even though it can be argued that it is somehow "legal" as a modifier of *value*. It really feels as if the word needed is playing the part of a noun in this sentence, and I can't articulate why. (That's why systematic descriptions of the grammars of natural languages are hard. There is very likely a way to tree this sentence that makes *maximum* obviously necessary if you invoke enough rules and corollaries.)